# NSAttributedString dataFromRange produces docx files without any tail indents

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

It is strange behaviour I found in NSAttributedString class. According to documentation, the objects of this class could produce a data of various types. I want to convert my text to the docx modern format. Again according to docs, I should use NSOfficeOpenXMLTextDocumentType document attribute. So I do:

```
// produce an NSAttributedString with all of the indents have set
let stringToConvert = currentDocument.computePrintableAttributedString(forProduct: product)`

// now create a document attributes dictionary
let documentAttributes = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSOfficeOpenXMLTextDocumentType]

// finally convert the string into the docx data
do {
    let convertedData = try stringToConvert.dataFromRange(fullLength, documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And everything works fine. I write the data into a file. And open it in MS Word. And everything looks fine... Except the document has lost all of the tail indents of the attributed string's paragraph style.

What am I do wrong? How to preserve the tail indents in the exported docx document?

I have tried the NSRTFTextDocumentType attribute and I got a really well formatted rtf file with all the tail indents in place.

What am I missing with NSOfficeOpenXMLTextDocumentType?

Comment: Maybe provide an example of the text (with tail indents) so that the behavior can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've found a bug/feature. I can reproduce the behaviour using TextEdit 1.11 running under OS X 10.11.4, and TextEdit uses `NSAttributedString` internally. Both tail indent and first line indent are preserved when saved as rtf; when saved as Word 97, 2003 or 2007 the tail indent is lost if the files are reopened in TextEdit; if the files are opened in Pages 5 the first line indent is lost as well. LibreOffice loses the tail indent when reading all three, the first line indent when reading 2003 or 2007, and the alignment when reading 2003. Over on a PC Word 2013 loses the tail indent reading all three, and the first line indent reading 2007.

Suggest you report the issue to Apple at bug report.apple.com

Comment: I did, thanks. But what's the workaround if Apple, as usual, will be fixing it for a couple of years? Maybe you know some external framework?

Comment: Sorry I don't know any framework, and even if so you'd have to be careful it didn't use the OS to do the conversion. The `textutil` command line app behaves as above, so undoubtedly uses the OS. Easiest workaround is just open the rtf in Word, looks fine. You might be able to use Applescript or Automator to script Word to open the rtf and save a docx.

Answer (score 0):

Filed a bug report. Did't change my code a bit. After the 10.11.6 update everything became to work as expected. Now NSAttributedString respects the right indents when exporting to NSOfficeOpenXMLTextDocumentType file format

**UPDATE:** turned out that I was wrong, I did change some code as I have remembered. And now I know how to work with NSData from NSAttributedString. As I discovered, correct NSData is being produced only if NSAttributedString contains negative tail indents in its NSParagraphStyle. Yes, NSAttributedString may work correctly with both negative and positive tail indents. But when exporting into an MS Word document, you should make sure that tail indents are negative.